# regex for rsyslog to exclude a pattern

Tags: regex, logging, rsyslog

I need an rsyslog regex to forward all the messages containing the word "FIREWALL" to a remote server. The original log format is:

> Jul 24 16:33:09 FW02 kernel: [3456825.472985] FIREWALL_DENY_IN: IN=eth2 OUT=MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:1b:78:e4:b3:24:08:00 SRC=10.101.103.193 DST=10.101.103.255 LEN=237 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51512 DPT=694 LEN=217

The required log format is to be without the kernel times:

> Jul 24 16:33:09 FW02 kernel: FIREWALL_DENY_IN: IN=eth2 OUT=MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:1b:78:e4:b3:24:08:00 SRC=10.101.103.193 DST=10.101.103.255 LEN=237 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51512 DPT=694 LEN=217

My experience with regex is basic. I was able to match the part I need to exclude with:

> [ *[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\]

but that's all. The regex must be validated on http://www.rsyslog.com/regex/

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no idea how rsyslog works, but perhaps the regex below can help

`^([^[]*).*\](.*)$`

Submatch 1:

`"Jul 24 16:33:09 FW02 kernel: "`

Submatch 2:

`" FIREWALL_DENY_IN: IN=eth2 OUT=MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:1b:78:e4:b3:24:08:00 SRC=10.101.103.193 DST=10.101.103.255 LEN=237 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51512 DPT=694 LEN=217"`